# How can I simulate clicking a button in a questdlg from a script

Tags: matlab, user-interface, dialog, automation

I am currently writing test routines to check that the graphical front end of a Matlab (R2014a) program calculates the same results as a script version (both rely on the same underlying methods).

So far I usually used the following pattern to find a window's and button's handle and execute the appropriate callback:

```
handleWindow = findall(0, 'Tag', figureName);
handleButton = findobj(handleWindow, 'Tag', buttonName);
callbackButton = get(handleButton, 'Callback');
callbackButton(handleWindow, []);
```

This works fine for all the self written figures created with GUIDE. I do however run into trouble when trying to autoanswer question dialogs (`questdlg`).

The fact that `uiwait` prevents the further execution of my testscript can easily be circumvented by using a timer to execute commands asynchronously until the dialog is closed. This already works fine for the `CloseRequestFcn`.

My problem is that there exists no real callback function for the buttons in a `questdlg` but instead it calls `uiresume(gcbf)`. Directly calling `uiresume(handleQdlg)` does not close the dialog.

Do you have any ideas how to simulate clicking those buttons or do you know of any more elegant ways to simulate clicking on buttons overall?

Comment: Just an idea: would it be too cumbersome to set up a 'Script flag' at the beginning of your code, that you would set to `true` if running the program from a script; then in that case you could simulate the answer to the `quesdlg` using a `swtich/case` statement and the dialog would be 'closed'?

Comment: @Benoit_11 It would be cumbersome if I try not to use global variables for this (and I do not really want to have those in the final vesions). I guess the easiest way would be to overload `questdlg` with another function which decides whether too call the builtin questdlg or a dummy-function with an easily accessible method to change its output. But it would probably best to just use a homemade dialog in all cases then. I would still not to have to adjust the "payload" to the tests.

Comment: Yes I agree I guess building a simple GUI for a question dialog will save you a lot of trouble!

Comment: I would also advise building your own small gui for this purpose, thats what i did in my gui toolbox.  You need to be careful with your method of finding objects, and manage if your tests find more than 1 handleWindow for example.

Comment: @matlabgui I agree, that I need to handle these things with care. But since I do not intend to use those in the finished product (only in test scripts that should start in a clean environment) having e.g. multiple windows with this title would indicate problems that appeared earlier in those scripts and should be fixed anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out that I was already on the right track. The delay for my timer was too short. It seems I tried resume the window when it was not yet waiting. With a longer delay it works.

Here is the function I ended up using:

```
function answerQuestDlg(obj, titleStr, index)
    %answerQuestDlg(obj, titleStr, index)
    %   Find the question dialog with specified title and simulate
    %   clicking the button with the appropriate index.
    %   If index is not 1, 2 or 3, simuluate pressing the X.

    allRootWindows = allchild(0);
    hQuestDlg = findobj(allRootWindows, 'Tag', titleStr);

    switch (index)
        case 1
            hButton = findobj(hQuestDlg, 'Tag', 'Btn1');
        case 2
            hButton = findobj(hQuestDlg, 'Tag', 'Btn2');
        case 3
            hButton = findobj(hQuestDlg, 'Tag', 'Btn3');
        otherwise
            callbackClose = get(hQuestDlg, 'CloseRequestFcn');
            callbackClose();
            return
    end

    set(hQuestDlg, 'CurrentObject', hButton);
    callbackButton = get(hButton, 'Callback');
    if ischar(callbackButton)
        callbackStr = strrep(callbackButton, 'gcbf', 'hQuestDlg');
        eval(callbackStr);
    else
        callbackButton();
    end
end
```